# Gem not installing, showing connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When I try to install gem like bundler or rake after creating new gemset , its not installing 
,but if i intall old version its working fine for me . Here are the error logs while installing gems

`gem install rake`

`Fetching: rake-0.9.2.2.gem (  7%)ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)`
`too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/rake-0.9.2.2.gem)`

Comment: Can you able to reach http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/ by browser without any problem?

Comment: Yes, Via browse i can read the gem also.But its very slow and process is been interrupted too.

Comment: This is caused due to very slow internet connection I think

Comment: My internet speed is 14 Mbps . Isn't that enough? Other downloads are working fine. Even i can download large files without interruption.

Comment: Have you tried these options?
http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/715http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=47913-too-many-connection-resets#comment_9681309

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=47913

Comment: @soundar Are you facing same issue while installing any gem?? I also faced the same issue with install rails3.1, bundler and rake gems.

Comment: @hbdev012 No I never faced it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was caused by the cachefly server.

It seems that the folks over at rubygems.org disabled this mirror and then people's downloads were able to continue successfully.

There is a thread over at rubygems.org [discussing this issue](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/1081-gem-install-problems-cannot-get-httpcacheflymirrorsrubygemsorg).

Answer (score 1):

Use **[DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)** to install gem separately .

**Edit** :

Please check if you curl or wget that URL:

wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/rails-2.3.8.gem

curl -O http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/rails-2.3.8.gem

If not, then the problem is with your internet connection, http proxy or 
provider.

If your browser works, might be due an HTTP proxy.

Comment: Sorry , I am not a windows user . I think u have sent me windows configuration link. Is it?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. production.cf.rubygems.org seems to be working fine for me. But for some gems it tries to fetch from some other mirror i.e. cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org which causes this error..

Comment: on ubuntu 11.10 with RVM setup

Comment: Working on ubuntu but on 10.10 with RVM only

Comment: IS it working to you ? If yes then please let us know the solution , so it will help to other .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when Capistrano was running a `bundle install` on a remote server. It seems to have been caused by a .rvmrc file in the project that I had not authorised.

So all I had to do to fix is was ssh into the server, `cd` into the project and accept the .rvmrc config file.

Answer (score 0):

got similar problem

```
gem install rails 
# after 5 minutes
WARNING:  Error fetching data: too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

gem install rails --source 'https://rubygems.org'
# after 5 minutes
WARNING:  Error fetching data: too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

but when I  create `Gemfile`

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

and run `bundle install` it works

my location is London, UK

(also created topic on http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/4494-too-many-connection-resets-when-gem-install-rails )

Answer (score 0):

Always check if your computer isn't downloading because of administrator privileges (in cmd, shell, or rubymine).